# Pointer to a Pointer to a LinkedList

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Why does this code return a segmentation fault?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node {
    struct node * next;
    int val;
} Node;

void foo(Node **head) {
    Node * curNode = *head;
    curNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    curNode->val = 5;
    curNode->next = NULL;
}

int main() {
    Node * head = NULL;
    foo(&head);
    printf("Val %d", head->val);
}
```

By my logic, I am giving a pointer to a pointer to the head of the LinkedList. Say the head of the LinkedList is stored at `0x1`, and the pointer that points to `0x1` is stored in `0x2`. So `&head` should point to `0x2` and `0x2` points to `0x1`. I change `0x2` to point instead of `0x555` (the  new value). So `&head` still points to `0x2` but `0x2` points to `0x555` instead of `0x1` now. But I get segmentation fault instead, why is this?

Comment: you cannot access 0x555 because probably it is not in your allocated memory address range

Comment: Did you use a debugger to trace your code?

Comment: `curNode->next = NULL;` --> `curNode->next = NULL; *head = curNode;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curNode` is a local variable. The `foo()` function does not change anything outside its scope.

That you set `curNode` to something on the first line of `foo()` is not doing any good, because you immediately overwrite it with the return value of `malloc()`. (Which you do not check the return value of, but that is another issue.)

Then, the `foo()` function just exits, and `curNode` goes out of scope, which means `curNode` is thrown away. The calling function sees no change.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're dereferencing `head` into a local pointer, and then only modifying that one—and not the actual pointer `head` is pointing to.

To fix:

```
void foo(Node **head) {
    *head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*head)->val = 5;
    (*head)->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: I see, but then how would I traverse and insert a node at the say end of the LinkedList? I need to set some temp variable to be the `curNode` which is akin to what I am doing right now

Comment: You could still construct a node by using a temp variable. But when you need to actually insert it to the list, you need to use the pointer referenced by the node in the list. So you can do `cur_node = ...;` and then `some_node->next = cur_node;`